# Selenium parallel test running conflict between multiple browser instances b/c share local storage?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, karma-jasmine

I started setting up protractor tests for an angular SPA. To speed up test running, I've setup Selenium to run tests in Firefox and Chrome using multiple instances for each browser.

Before each test case we clear localStorage so we are certain of our starting position.

However, today I uncovered a conflict. Since a browser with two instances, if pointing at the same domain, it will share localStorage between the two. So if I have two tests running in parallel, and one requires a user to be logged in, while the other requires user to be logged out -- well, the first test will log user in, and now the user in the second browser instance will also be logged in (because localStorage got set/updated in both).

So now, one of my tests just failed because it found itself on the wrong page.

Is there any simple way to overcome this problem? (That does not involve setting up a server and multiple instances, or spending $2,000/mo on Saucelabs/Browserstack...)

Comment: We actually have a similar problem. We've tried to open up "incognito" windows but, unfortunately, from what we've discovered - they share the same local storage too.

Comment: Have you tried CirceCI? It has container system - each browser is started on a separate machine!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, i was facing the same problem and here is the solution i got:

1. You will have to make a copy of the framework and store it in two different places in your local machine.
2. You will have to create different listening ports for each instance launch in selenium, you can do the same by configuring the testng.xml that is being used for launching the automation tests.